# Update data while slow internet connection in Django rest api

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Views.py

```
  class Bet(UpdateAPIView):
      """
      Sample method
      """
      def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         with transaction.atomic():

            instance = self.get_object()

            if request.data.get('i') == 1:
                #some code 
            elif request.data.get('i') == 2:
                #some code 
            elif request.data.get('i') == 3:
                #some code 
            elif request.data.get('i') == 4:
                #some code 
            else:
               ## a large block of code also **it create a new entry for request user and bet in 3-4 tables.**


               instance.user = request.user
               instance.save()
           return custom_render(status_code, message, response_status)
```

Here two users (user1 and user2) are calling the API at same time in slow internet connection.

Now due to slow connection both APIs passed all the validation and code execution reach to **else block**. 
and will create entry for both user.

Here My problem is if any user accept the bet then nobody can accept the same bet.

In fast internet connection, its working fine by checking request.data.get('i') == 1 True and return the response.

Comment: you already have a condition, if a user accept the bet. Just check the data from your database, who has accepted the bet. If the value exists in the DB then reject else accept the entry.

Comment: Have you tried celery?

Comment: @Akshay Not now , Although i fixed it temporarily  by storing cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

```
class Bet(UpdateAPIView):
  """
  Sample method
  """
  def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

     if request.data.get('i') == 1:
            #some code 
     elif request.data.get('i') == 2:
            #some code 
     elif request.data.get('i') == 3:
            #some code 
     elif request.data.get('i') == 4:
            #some code 
     else:
           ## a large block of code also **it create a new entry for request user and bet in 3-4 tables.**
        with transaction.atomic():
           try:
              instance=Model.objects.filter(pk=pk).select_for_update(nowait=True, of=('self',))
           except:
              return something
           instance.user = request.user
           instance.save()

     return custom_render(status_code, message, response_status)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankush its working fine. can you please explain about 
nowait=True, of=('self',)

Comment: @somil nowait clause is to acquire lock immediately and of clause let you know which table/model it should acquire the lock.

Answer (score 4):

This theory is untested but I suspect you could throw a [`.select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) on your view's queryset attribute.

`.get_object()` calls `.get_queryset()` and since your code executes in an atomic block the row should be locked until the transaction is completed.

```
class Bet(UpdateView):
    queryset = Bet.objects.all().select_for_update()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            instance = self.get_object()
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As your connection is slow and you are updating data via `REST API` being consumed by the client(ex. Android or IOS App maybe), there is no solution to carry out such thing. What you can do is, store the data in the client's local storage and `sync` it with your API once the connection speed is fast enough. You can check the `ServiceWorker` in web browser to understand the whole concept. basically, you will need something that works as a service worker for your API client/consumer app. Also, try to perform an `atomic` transaction with your database.

Comment: transaction.atomic() is already in my code, Is  there anything else which i need to add in my code for atomic transaction.

Comment: client is Android and IOS , i am unable to manage from their end.

Comment: according to me, you should store the data locally. once the device gets into faster enough network. you can call the API to update data. to maintain atomicity of data, while storing data into local storage store the exact date and time of data creation and update the data in backend accordingly. it's a broad concept.

Comment: If i am not wrong then locally means Android or IOS . 
and i need to fix it by django or python.

Comment: locally means API client's (android or ios device's storage). You can store data in android by using shared preferences, for ios there should be similar also. You can use json format to store that data in the device storage. Once device git network, You can send that data to api.

Answer (score -2):

Use [`atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/) transactions.

According to [Official django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)

> Open transactions have a performance cost for your database server. To minimize this overhead, keep your transactions as short as possible. This is especially important if you’re using atomic() in long-running processes, outside of Django’s request / response cycle.

Comment: "If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back."
Here My code doesn't return any exception.

Comment: If you are already using the `atomic` transaction as shown in the edited post, you can check the status of the bet in `pre_save` signal.